# Tensorflow not importing properly - Tensor flow version 2.3.0, Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pycharm, anaconda

I am trying to resolve below issue with many permutation combination but end-up with some issue.

**Environment used:**

> python 3.8.3  Anaconda 1.9.12 ,
> Tensorflow CPU version 2.3 which supports python 3.8 as per Tensorflow website.
> Created new environment in Anaconda for this.

I also degrade python 3.6 version with same Tensorflow version but same issue.
I chose interpreter path as new environment path ( tried python.exe and pythonw.exe both)
I used pip installer to install Tensorflow.

**Brief error desc:**

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

**Work around:**

I have created new environment in Anaconda and installed with above environment settings

```
Error console: raceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * ImportError: DLL load failed while importing
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vid/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Help Request:

Can anyone here help me to resolve the issue. Where I am doing mistake? I tried various version of python but seems it is not working.

I have seen many solution provided here like..

1. Degrade python version till 3.6
2. Tensor installation using conda install..
3. Installing MS VC++ 2015 package
   , etc..

But I have not degraded Tensorflow version because its mentioned the latest version can run for python 3.8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

** Issue Resolved **

**Solution:**
As I was using Anaconda so as per advise from anaconda its better to install the tensorflow using conda install command (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda). Conda installation ensured all the python and tensor dependencies version and packages will be taken care. Refer to below package which has suggested to during my conda installation.

Command and package file details are below..
Automatically Anaconda chose Tensorflow 2.2.0 version (While for my case during pip installation it was 2.3.0. Python 3.7.9 version while I had Python 3.8.3)

**Console content:**

(base) C:\Users\Vid>conda create -n tensor tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: C:\Users\Vid\anaconda3\envs\tensor

added / updated specs:
- tensorflow

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
_tflow_select-2.2.0        |            eigen           3 KB
absl-py-0.9.0              |           py37_0         168 KB
astor-0.8.1                |           py37_0          47 KB
blinker-1.4                |           py37_0          22 KB
brotlipy-0.7.0             |py37he774522_1000         336 KB
cachetools-4.1.1           |             py_0          12 KB
certifi-2020.6.20          |           py37_0         156 KB
cffi-1.14.2                |   py37h7a1dbc1_0         227 KB
chardet-3.0.4              |        py37_1003         193 KB
cryptography-3.1           |   py37h7a1dbc1_0         536 KB
gast-0.2.2                 |           py37_0         155 KB
google-auth-1.21.1         |             py_0          56 KB
google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1 |             py_2          20 KB
google-pasta-0.2.0         |             py_0          46 KB
grpcio-1.31.0              |   py37he7da953_0         1.5 MB
h5py-2.10.0                |   py37h5e291fa_0         808 KB
importlib-metadata-1.7.0   |           py37_0          52 KB
intel-openmp-2020.2        |              254         1.6 MB
keras-applications-1.0.8   |             py_1          29 KB
keras-preprocessing-1.1.0  |             py_1          37 KB
libprotobuf-3.13.0         |       h200bbdf_0         1.8 MB
markdown-3.2.2             |           py37_0         136 KB
mkl-2020.2                 |              256       109.3 MB
mkl-service-2.3.0          |   py37hb782905_0         210 KB
mkl_fft-1.1.0              |   py37h45dec08_0         116 KB
mkl_random-1.1.1           |   py37h47e9c7a_0         233 KB
numpy-1.19.1               |   py37h5510c5b_0          22 KB
numpy-base-1.19.1          |   py37ha3acd2a_0         3.8 MB
oauthlib-3.1.0             |             py_0          91 KB
opt_einsum-3.1.0           |             py_0          54 KB
pip-20.2.2                 |           py37_0         1.7 MB
protobuf-3.13.0            |   py37h6538335_0         535 KB
pyasn1-0.4.8               |             py_0          57 KB
pyasn1-modules-0.2.7       |             py_0          68 KB
pyjwt-1.7.1                |           py37_0          49 KB
pyreadline-2.1             |           py37_1         143 KB
pysocks-1.7.1              |           py37_1          28 KB
python-3.7.9               |       h60c2a47_0        14.4 MB
requests-oauthlib-1.3.0    |             py_0          23 KB
rsa-4.6                    |             py_0          26 KB
scipy-1.5.2                |   py37h9439919_0        11.8 MB
setuptools-49.6.0          |           py37_0         771 KB
tensorboard-2.2.1          |     pyh532a8cf_0         2.4 MB
tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.6.0|             py_0         630 KB
tensorflow-2.1.0           |eigen_py37hd727fc0_0           4 KB
tensorflow-base-2.1.0      |eigen_py37h49b2757_0        35.4 MB
tensorflow-estimator-2.1.0 |     pyhd54b08b_0         251 KB
termcolor-1.1.0            |           py37_1           8 KB
urllib3-1.25.10            |             py_0          98 KB
werkzeug-0.16.1            |             py_0         258 KB
win_inet_pton-1.1.0        |           py37_0           9 KB
wincertstore-0.2           |           py37_0          14 KB
wrapt-1.12.1               |   py37he774522_1          49 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:       190.4 MB
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a couple of days back.
I would suggest you to download Anaconda 2020.02 for a seamlessly smooth experience with TensorFlow 2.

After installation;

You can execute the following instructions and command to solve the issue: (do not include inverted commas)

1. Open Anaconda Prompt
2. type: "create --name py3-TF2.0 python = 3"
3. press "y" to continue
   After successful completion:
4. type "conda activate py3-TF2.0"
5. type "pip install matplotlib"
6. type "pip install tensorflow==2.3.0"
7. type "conda deactivate"
8. type "pip install ipykernel"
9. type "conda install nb_conda_kernels"

Now exit the Anaconda prompt and open the Anaconda Navigator application. Switch to "py3-TF2.0" from the base environment using the Environment tab. Install Jupyter in the specified environment. After successful installation, open Jupyter notebook and switch to "py3-TF2.0" kernel using Kernel Tab. You're good to go for using TensorFlow 2.